# How to get property from object array?

Tags: javascript

I have this array:

```
var arr1 = [{id:124,name:'qqq'}, 
           {id:589,name:'www'}, 
           {id:45,name:'eee'},
           {id:567,name:'rrr'}]
```

I need to get all Id's.

```
var Id's = [124,589,45,567];
```

What's the elegant way to retrieve all id's property from object array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
var output = arr1.map(function(obj){ return obj.id; })
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [**`Array#map`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

> *The `map()` method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in this array.*

```js
var arr1 = [{
  id: 124,
  name: 'qqq'
}, {
  id: 589,
  name: 'www'
}, {
  id: 45,
  name: 'eee'
}, {
  id: 567,
  name: 'rrr'
}];
var op = arr1.map(function(item) {
  return item.id;
});
//Using Arrow functions `arr1.map((item) => (item.id));`
console.log(op);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = arr1.map(function(obj) {
   return obj.id
});
```

Comment: Please add more details  to your solution